# Get all products of user in Bugzilla

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

I want to get all products from "products" table for a particular user.

Something like:

```
"select product_name from products where user='user_email'";
```

Can anybody help me to understand the relationship between the "products" and "profiles" tables in Bugzilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer but I got very useful help from [this](https://searchcode.com/file/22897644/bugzilla-4.2.1/describecomponents.cgi) link.